# Compute distances to a given point using iterators

Tags: c++

I am doing an exercise, where I am supposed to calculate the distances to a given query point from a range of points using iterators. Now I am quite new to iterators, so I was hoping someone could clarify some things for me. The function I am supposed to fill out is this:

```
// Computes the distances of all points in the range [begin,end) to a given query point.
//
// The results are stored in the Range starting with distanceBegin having the same length
// as the range of points. The i-th element of the range stores the distance of the i-th point
// in the range to the query point as a double value.
// 
// The supplied iterators can be assumed to be bidirectional
template<class SetIterator, class DistanceIterator>
void computeDistances(
    SetIterator begin, SetIterator end,//pointers to the start and end of the set of points
    Vector const& query, //the query point 
    DistanceIterator distanceBegin //iterator to the beginning of the range storing the distances
    )
    {


    }
```

My question is: How should I attack this problem. I guess I should iterate through the range of points by incrementing and then calculating the length between different points as len(iterated_point-query). But does the class vector have an in-built iterator? And what exactly is the DistanceIterator. Is this where I store my results for the distances or where do I store these?

Answer (score 1):

> How should I attack this problem? I guess I should iterate through the range of points by incrementing and then calculating the length between different points as len(iterated_point-query).

Yep, sounds correct! :)

> Does the class vector have an in-built iterator?

Without any more context it's impossible to say. However I would assume that in this case `Vector` is like a mathematical vector (x,y,z,..) and the points are similarly (x,y,z,...). So

-`[begin, end)` is an array of `Vector` objects

-`[distanceBegin, distanceBegin + std::distance(begin, end))` is an array of doubles.

> And what exactly is the DistanceIterator. Is this where I store my results for the distances or where do I store these?

Yes. It's the iterator to the first element of the array in which you store your distances. Here's what I believe the question is asking for

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>


// Forward declaration of Vector (provide your own)
struct Vector; 


// Converts a Vector object to a double, by calculating the distance between 
// it and the origin using Pythagoras' theorem.
double len(const Vector& v) { return std::sqrt(v._x*v._x + v._y*v._y + v._z*v._z); }


// Your function
template<class SetIterator, class DistanceIterator>
void computeDistances(
    SetIterator begin, SetIterator end,
    Vector const& query,
    DistanceIterator distanceBegin  
)
{
    std::transform(begin, end, distanceBegin, [query](Vector& v) { return len(v - query); });
}
```

The std::transform with the lambda is equivalent to

```
for (; begin != end; ++begin, ++distanceBegin)
{
    *distanceBegin = len(*begin - query);
}
```

and in order to make this work, you should provide your own implementation of Vector, and change the function + lambda accordingly. [Here is my minimal and very simplistic implementation of this code.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1b8ec10db77ee326)

### Addendum:

I should add that there are many better ways of writing the computeDistances function. First, our `operator - ()` creates an additional Vector every time we call it, so let's rewrite len() such that it does the subtraction with the elements

```
double len(const Vector& v1, const Vector& v2)
{
    return std::sqrt(v1._x*v2._x + v1._y*v2._y + v1._z*v2._z);
}
```

Then let's replace the very verbose and hard to read computeDistances with either

```
// Solution 1 : simple and concise, but prone to one-off errors
for (unsigned i = 0; i < points.size(); ++i)
{
    distances[i] = len(points[i], query);  
}

// Solution 2 
// Get indices implementation from https://github.com/klmr/cpp11-range
for (unsigned i : indices(points))
{
    distances[i] = len(points[i], query);
}
```

If instead you want the most generic solution possible then you could then power up your code with templates and make it all container independent, although this is very verbose. [I had a go at making such a thing here.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/276367f00c1b57a9)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest having a look at `std::transform` and how that works: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform

You will quickly notice the similarity: the need to iterate from `begin` to `end` and for each of the elements perform a calculation (distance to `query` in your case). The result of that calculation which takes an element in the range `[begin, end[` will be stored using the given output iterator (`distanceBegin`) as it is the iterator into the collection that will hold the calculated results.

To get you going, consider the following example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    // Range of elements over which we need to iterate
    auto myRange = {1, 2, 3};
    auto begin = std::begin(myRange);
    auto end = std::end(myRange);

    // Reference element
    auto reference = 2.0;

    // Container holding result and iterator into that container
    std::vector<double> results;
    auto output = std::back_inserter(results);

    // Lambda function performing the calculation: for a given element, a simple calculation is made w.r.t. to a reference value
    auto calculation = [&reference](const int &element){ return element - reference; };

    // Perform the calculation
    std::transform(begin, end, output, calculation);

    // Print out the results
    for (const auto &result : results) {
        std::cout << result << std::endl;
    }
}
```

This example uses C++11 features (`auto` and `lambdas`), but these are not strictly required and can be easily adapted to C++03.
As you can see, `std::transforms` iterates over the elements of range `[begin, end[` and calls `calculation` with the dereferenced iterator (i.e. it passes the element referenced by the 'current' iterator) and stores the result using the given output iterator.

Now in your case, you basically need to write a function that does what `std::transform` does, but for your specific case.